# How do I create an empty array in zsh?

Tags: zsh

This is a pretty straightforward question. I want to assign a variable with an empty array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

This turns out to be an easy one.

To create a **global** empty array:

```
things=()
```

To create a **local** empty array:

```
local -a things
```